# I want to get notified if my facebook app's users check in any location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-checkins

I am writing an app to offer something to FB users depending on their locations.
Current situation : I know how to check one specific user's location. 
I may periodically check all my users locations in a loop and compare them with their last positions.

Question: Is there a better method to get notified if any user of my fb app checks in ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, realtime was the key I was looking for.
I found an [example](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-facebooks-realtime-updates-and-subscription-api/) and want to share it here :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [Realtime Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/), which is a feature that pings your app when a User updates their account. You can activate real time updates from your App Settings page, and configure it to listen to user checkins.

The facebook documentation shows how you can listen to updates. It's much more efficient to use this method, as you avoid making unnecessary calls to Facebook to check each user's checkins.

Comment: Just be aware that there seems to be a documentation bug in the FB docs. Instead of enabling 'checkins' for the subscription, you must enable 'feed'.  Then user checkins will appear at your callback url as changed_fields=feed